# Trying to install ubuntu with built in partitioner

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to install ubuntu and use the built in partitioner but I cannot find the 'free space' option to click. I looked online and there should be an option that says free space but it isnt there. Any advice would be appreciated This is for a dual boot on windows 7 btw.

[image: 1]

Comment: You have to create the free space.

Comment: You have to click `New Partition Table..." to create new partition scheme for your HDD. Be caution, it will wipe entire HDD.

Answer (score 2):

Boot back into Windows and use the Disk Management tool (search for "partition" in the start menu) to "shrink" one of the discs.  That will create the free space that you can use to install Ubuntu. I always use the Windows tools to resize discs on a windows machine.  It helps reduce the possibility of data loss.

[howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/) has a nice tutorial on how to use the Disk Management tool.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of space in /dev/sda2 which is of type ntfs. I will say either create a new partition while installing Ubuntu or go back to Windows. Under Disk management - create some space for Ububtu. To be very simple you just need around 10 GB+ kind of space for Ubuntu...Ubuntu installer can then create / and swap partition for you automatically and then you can install ubuntu.
What is that /dev/sdb? Is it the live USB or CD? If that is another hard drive - may be you can install ubuntu on that. 
Once the installation is done - test grub2 and if needed use boot-repair for dual boot(Win or Ubuntu). Hope this helps.